# Spring Logging clean design solution

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring rest service which needs some logging to be added.

Logging is handled by a single schema pojo which is written to the logs, once per request, at the end of it. So thats one log line per request.

Fields of the pojo will be set/updated throughout the app, and eventually written to the logs before the request completes.

Different sections of business logic would update certain sections of the pojo.

I was thinking of using aspects, but the pojo has a strict schema, something like:

```
class AppLogger{
 private String userId;
 private int numberOfOrders;
 private long ts;
 private String command;
}
```

so for example, for tracking orders, it would be logged as:

```
public processOrders(){
 int numberOfOrders = getNumberOfOrders();
 AppLogger.getInstance().setNumberOrOrders(numberOfOrders);
}
```

Are there better ways to cleanly handle this in spring ?